# Combining two ggplot objects from different function calls?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to implement a graphing library where I need a bit more flexibility than what is currently provided by ggplot. I am interested in going in a functional programming kind of way.

Currently, I have a barchart which is defined as

```
make_bar <- function(data, x, n_cols)
{
  #Data: Dataframe or tibble 
  #x: Factor singular column
  #output: ggplot object 
  
  n_colors = nrow(distinct(data[x])) 
  
    if (n_colors != length(n_cols)) { 
        difference <- abs(n_colors - length(colors))
        colors <- head(colors, difference) 
        }

  plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = .data[[x]],
                          tooltip = .data[[x]],
                          data_id = .data[[x]])) +
                geom_bar_interactive(fill=custom_colour_palette(colors))
}
```

Which very nicely returns a bar chart. Now I want the functionality to write a function called "add_line" which should then be applied to the barchart if one wishes to do so. The line function as is right now is:

```
add_line <- function(data, x) { 
  data %>% 
  count(.data[[x]]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(.data[[x]], n)) +
  geom_line(group=1) 
    
}
```

So now I have two lists, but is there any easy - or best practice - way to add such two lists to create one combined plot with the line overlayed on the barchart?

Code for reproducbility can be called with:

```
data <- mpg 
h <- add_line(data, 'manufacturer')
x <- make_bar(data, 'manufacturer', 15)
# x + h ? does not work and shouldn't but such a functionality would be nice
```

Comment: Each function is creating it's own `ggplot` object. There's not really an easy way to combine those into one plot overlayed on the other. You've set up two completely different access systems. It's better if the functions would just return a geom or a list of things you could add to a `ggplot` object outside the function.

Comment: Is that geom_bar_interactive from ggiraph?

Comment: Where does custom_colour_palette come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to what @MrFlick has said, here's how you return a `geom` object in `add_line` that can be added onto the base bar chart:

```r
add_line <- function(data, x) { 
  geom_line(
    aes_string(x = x, y = "n"),
    data = count(data, .data[[x]]), 
    group = 1
  ) 
}
```

Then the following should work:

```r
x <- make_bar(mpg, "manufacturer", 15)
h <- add_line(mpg, "manufacturer")
x + h
```

The `aes_string` allows for using character strings rather than expressions, really useful for dynamic column choices.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. The proportions are a bit off, since the line is not directly fitted to the tops of the barchart, but I guess that will be the price of the approach ;-)